# Import csv to mogodb collection- Invalid UTF-8 character detected

Tags: mongodb, csv, utf-8, ascii, mongoimport

I am trying to import csv file into mongodb collections by following command

```
mongoimport -d mydb -c locations --type csv --file locations.csv --headerline
```

it is giving

```
exception:Invalid UTF8 character detected
```

command file locations.csv is showing ASCII character with CR lines 
i have tried

```
iconv -f ASCII -t utf8 -c locations.csv
```

to remove invalid character but getting the same error in importing the file

Comment: could you check if this helps?? iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t utf8 -c locations.csv

Comment: i have tried..not helpful

Comment: Ammar - Are you able to resolved this error?  Regards, neha